# Loopback validateUpsert set to false does not work, still runs validations

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a loopback model set like this:

```
{
  "name": "MyModel",
  "plural": "MyModels",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": false
  },
...
}
```

When using `CREATE` or `POST`, it runs fine, runs all validations, etc, which of course it should. However, if I use `PATCH /MyModels/{id}`, passing only one attribute in the JSON data (because I only want to update that specific attribute value), I expect it NOT to run the validations on the attributes that I did not pass.

Because it says here:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#advanced-options
that if you set `validateUpsert` to false, `upsert` will NOT run the validations.

And it says here:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Controlling-data-access.html#comprehensive-accesstype-property-and-end-point
that `PATCH /MyModels/{id}` corresponds to `updateAttributes` and `PATCH /MyModels`corresponds to `upsert`.

So I was hoping that it will not run the validations on attributes that I did not pass in `PATCH` methods. But still it does. It still even does the `presence` validation.

How can I use `PATCH` that `loopback` will simply just ignore (not validate & not update) the attributes that I did not pass?

I'm currently using `loopback ^3.0.0`.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the put method and pass only the field you want to update :

eg /MyModels/{id}

Here id is the unique identifier for the row and pass the body like this :

{
"name" : "New name"
}

In this case only the name value will be validated and updated . Other fields remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this in your model file.
"replaceOnPUT": false